# Convert string to date django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to convert string to date in template using template tag but it doesn't work

```
{% load templat_tag_file %}  
<input name="range2" type="date" {% if request.GET.range2 %}
value="{{ request.GET.range2|convert_str_date }}"{% endif %}/>
```

my templat_tag_file.py :

```
from datetime import datetime
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def convert_str_date(value):
    return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

I got this error: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: What you mean by *"doesn't work"*? Please do provide more information regarding your issue.

Comment: i got this error : time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: what is the format of time data? is it like `1988-02-22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign a python `date` object to `<input type="date">`. you need to convert it to string:

```
from datetime import datetime
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def convert_str_date(value):
    return str(datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
```

also as @quick mentions you need to use `request.GET` instead `request.Get`

```
{% load templat_tag_file %}  
<input name="range2" type="date" {% if request.GET.range2 %}
value="{{ request.GET.range2|convert_str_date }}"{% endif %}/>
```

**Update:**

You don't need to define templatetag, if the format is like `1988-02-22`, this will work:

```
<input name="range2" type="date" value="{{ request.GET.range2 }}" />
```

```html
<input name="range2" type="date" value="1988-02-22" />
```

Comment: request.GET.range2 is string and it doesn't work so i want to convert it to date

Comment: @NadaEssam what is the format of `range2`? is it like `1988-02-22`

Comment: @NadaEssam then i think `<input name="range2" type="date" value="{{ request.GET.range2 }}" />` will work.

Comment: I want display the date value get by the request in the date input but it doesn't work

Comment: will you show the source code after the page rendered some thing like `<input name="range2" type="date" value="1988-02-22" />`

Comment: @NadaEssam i added a snippet which runs fine.

Comment: the source code after the page rendered: <input name="range2" type="date" value="" />

Comment: `value`  is empty which means `{{ request.GET.range2 }}` is empty.

Comment: that is `range1`. so you have to use `{{ request.GET.range1 }}`

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide enough information. I guess you should use request.GET instead request.Get:

```
{% load templat_tag_file %}  
<input name="range2" type="date" {% if request.GET.range2 %}
value="{{ request.GET.range2|convert_str_date }}"{% endif %}/>
```